# Manejo de listas de objetos

Tags: java

necesito crear una lista de carreras(universitarias) y agregarles materias. el tema es que cuando elijo una carrera, me lista todas las materias de todas las carreras.

```
    Carrera sistemas =  nuevaCarrera("Licenciatura en Sistemas", 252,"Plan B");
    Carrera economia =  nuevaCarrera("Licenciatura en Economia", 25,"Plan A");
    
    Materia m = new Materia(sistemas,"Elementos de Informatica", 1, 1,52,false, false);
    
    Materia m1 = new Materia(economia,"Calculo Matematico", 2, 2,101,false, true);
```

CONSTRUCTOR DE LA CLASE MATERIA

```
public Materia(Carrera carreraNombre,String nombre, int anio, int cuatrimestre, int codigo, 
                    boolean condicion,
                    boolean promocionable) {
        setCarrera(carreraNombre);
        setNombreMateria(nombre);
        setAnio(anio);
        setCuatrimestre(cuatrimestre);
        setCodigo(codigo);
        setOptativa(condicion);
        setPromocionable(promocionable);
        
    }
    CUANDO CREO LA MATERIA, LE PASO UNA CARRERA Y SE LA ASIGNO A LA LISTA DE MATERIAS
    public void setCarrera(Carrera carreraNombre) {
        carrera = carreraNombre;
        carreraNombre.setMaterias(this);
    }


    CONSTRUCTOR DE LA CLASE CARRERA


    public Carrera(String nombre, int codigo, String planEstudio) {
        setNombre(nombre);
        setCodigo(codigo);
        setPlan(planEstudio);
        materias = new ArrayList<Materia>();
    }
    SET Y GET DE LA LISTA DE MATERIAS 
    public void setMaterias(Materia asignaturas){
        materias.add(asignaturas);
    }    
    public ArrayList<Materia> getMaterias(){
       return materias;
    }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y donde listas las materias??? porque no veo donde lo haces, los constructores parecen estar bien... salvo que materias este mal definido... no lo estas mostrando eso...

Answer (score 0):

Permíteme hacerte una recomendación. Parece que tienes una lista de Carreras, cada una tiene Materias, un nombre, etc.

Por lo que te sugeriré un diseño simplificado que podría servirte de guía:

```
public class Materia
{
    private String m_nombre;

    public Materia(String nombre)
    {
        m_nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getNombre()
    {
        return m_nombre;
    }
}

public class Carrera
{
    private String        m_nombre;
    private List<Materia> m_materias;

    public Carrera(String nombre, Materia[] materias)
    {
        m_nombre          = nombre;
        m_materias        = Arrays.asList(materias);
    }

    public String getNombre()
    {
        return m_nombre;
    }

    public List<Materia> getMaterias()
    {
        return m_materias;
    }
}
```

Entonces, simulemos tu hipotética lista de Carreras:

```
List<Carrera> carreras = Arrays.asList
(
    new Carrera("Ingeniería",   new Materia[] { new Materia("Matemáticas"), new Materia("Biología") }),
    new Carrera("Arquitectura", new Materia[] { new Materia("Álgebra"),     new Materia("Física")   }),
);
```

Si seleccionas una carrera de tu lista, te devolverá solo las materias de dicha carrera:

```
Materia[] materias = carreras.get(1).getMaterias();
```

---

También podrías crear un método de búsqueda secuencial que busque una carrera por nombre y te devuelva las materias de dicha carrera:

```
private static Materias[] encontrarCarreraPorNombre(List<Carrera> carreras, String busqueda)
{
    Materia[] materias = new Materia[0];

    for (Carrera carrera : carreras)
    {
        if (busqueda.equals(carrera.getNombre()))
        {
            materias = carrera.getMaterias();
            break;
        }
    }

    return materias;
}
```

Entonces:

```
 Materia[] materias = encontrarCarreraPorNombre(carreras, "Arquitectura");
```

Comment: muchas gracias por responder! lo voy a probar!